# remove items from a combobox

Tags: java, swing, combobox

I have a method that populates a combo box from a database. It does this using a doctors ID to populate it. The problem is that when I change the ID to another person instead of clearing the combo box and then populating it again it just adds to the end of list.

```java
public void FillTimings() {
    theapptTime.removeAllItems();
    theapptTime.repaint();

    String strDate = theTdate.getText().trim();

    String strDoctor = (String) theTstaffname.getSelectedItem();
    System.out.println(strDoctor);

    try {
        db.dbConnect();
        String docId = db.getdociD(strDoctor);
        ResultSet rs = db.getTimings(strDate, docId);

        while (rs.next()) {
            theapptTime.addItem(rs.getString(1));
            rs.close();
        }
    } catch (SQLException e1) {
        System.out.println("fail");
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

That is the code.

Can someone help me.

Comment: It would be helpful if you would add a tag for the programming language. That might draw the attention of the right folks here.

Comment: Check out this link: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319927

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).
 But as mentioned in the document, factor out the D/B & instead hard-code some data.

Comment: Also note that a [`DefaultComboBoxModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultComboBoxModel.html) has methods `removeElement(Object)`, `removeElement(int)` and `removeAll()`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to First Declare a DefaultComboBoxModel

```
    DefaultComboBoxModel dt=new DefaultComboBoxModel();
```

set your combo box model to this model

```
    theapptTime.setModel(dt);
```

next inside your code
update it to

```
    db.dbConnect();
    String docId = db.getdociD(strDoctor);
    ResultSet rs = db.getTimings(strDate, docId);
    dt.removeAllElements();
    while (rs.next()) {
        dt.addElement(rs.getString(1));
        rs.close();
    }
```

it will work!! cheers!!

Comment: where are you setting the combobox model?? after doing what i have explained whats happening?? good if you can post code and whats the output so that i can advice you further..coz i made a sample application and its working fine

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
DefaultComboBoxModel dt = (DefaultComboBoxModel) theapptTime.getModel();
dt.addElement("item 1");
```